# How to launch a sound at the reception of a push notification even if the phone is on silent mode with Ionic?

Tags: ionic-framework, push-notification

Is there a way to launch a sound on the user's phone when he receives a push notification even if the phone is on silent mode with ionic ?

I didn't find any information about this.

Answer (score 0):

- I'm Actually A beginner to Ionic but I haded the Same Issue Once ...
- I fixed it using Ionic Native Audio Plugin. when the sound setting in
  the phone is set to MUTE - It plays anyway.

[here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/native-audio/) Try this. it might Help